# Calculate the number of days between today and specific date using DAX in Powerpivot

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a date column in my data model. I want to calculate the # of days between today and the date in the column using DAX.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a calculated column with this formula:

```
=today()-[DATE]
```

and change the value of column in numeric:

[image]